# Array JSON of obj to string

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I have a array of `objects` like this:

```js
cost arr = [
    {"value": "Surname"},
    {"value": "Address"},
    {"value": "E-mail"},
    {"value": "Telephone number"}
];
```

How Can I get only the keys? Meaning, just
`Surname`, `Address`, `E-mail`, and `Telephone number`, instead of the key-value pairs like `value: Surname`.

I want to have this output I use `JSON.stringify()`.

```
Surname, Address, Telephone number
```

Comment: jsonArray.map(o => o.value).join(", ");

Answer (score 0):

jsonArray.map((item)=>  item.value).toString();

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this (I don't know if your aren't interested in the E-Mail value. If you are, just remove the filter function:

```
const values = [{"value":" Surname"},{"value":" Address"},{"value":" E-mail"},{"value":" Telephone number"}]
                    .filter(it => it.value.trim() !== 'E-mail')
                    .map(it => it.value.trim()).join(", ");
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do it like this

```
const arr = [{"value":" Surname"},{"value":" Address"},{"value":" E-mail"},{"value":" Telephone number"}]

const result = arr.map((item) => item.value).toString()
```

value of result is now 'Surname, Address, E-mail, Telephone number'